# Java NumberFormat fails to parse an amount with a currency's international symbol

Tags: java, locale, currency

I need to parse an amount with a currency's *international symbol* rather than the currency's *symbol*, and extract the amount.
That is, I need to parse *14.00 **USD*** rather than ***$**14.00* or *14.00 **CAD*** rather than ***$**14.00*.
For that I have placed the following code, for example:

```java
NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.forLanguageTag("en-CA")).parse("14.00 CAD").doubleValue();
```

The above code snippet throws an exception `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number` as *DecimalFormat* obtained thru *getCurrencyInstance()* expects the currency string to begin with either **$** or **$-**.
I find it hard to believe that *NumberFormat* cannot deal with a legitimate currency string such as *14.00 CAD*; more likely, I have not found a way to use it correctly.
So how can an amount with a currency's *international symbol* such as *14.00 CAD* be parsed?

Comment: You need to use RegEx

Comment: It does seem like this should be possible.  Calling NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance([Locale.ROOT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html#ROOT)) and then [setting its currency](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setCurrency%28java.util.Currency%29) comes close;  it formats numbers as, for instance, `CA$ 14.00`.  Note that using `NumberFormat.getInstance` rather than getCurrencyInstance will ignore characters after the numeric value when parsing.